# Asking for an English version of Aleksandrov's famous 1939 paper in Convex Geometry

Tags: reference-request, convex-geometry, convex-analysis, translation

I have difficulty even in finding a Russian version of the next paper:

"Aleksandrov, A. D., Almost everywhere existence of the second differential of a convex
function and some properties of convex surfaces connected with it (in Russian).
Uchenye Zapiski Leningrad. Gos. Univ., Math. Ser. 6 (1939), 3–35"

This is a quite famous paper which also appears in other questions in MathOverflow, e.g., [Aleksandrov's proof of the second order differentiability of convex functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353950/aleksandrovs-proof-of-the-second-order-differentiability-of-convex-functions). Since Leningard has changed its name to St. Petersburg, I am not sure what's the current name of this journal.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This journal no longer exists. Quick search shows that even the Russian original is not available on Internet, not speaking of translation. What I would do in this case, is ask my library ILL (Interlibrary loan). They are always able to find such journals. But you will obtain only the Russian original in this way. Apparently no translation exists.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This paper is contained in the 1-st volume of Aleksandrov's Selected works. This has an English translation:

Alexandrov, A. D.
Reshetnyak, Yu. G. (ed.)
Selected works. Part 1: Selected scientific papers. Ed. by Yu. G. Reshetnyak and S. S. Kutateladze, transl. from the Russian by P. S. V. Naidu. (English) Zbl 0960.01035
Amsterdam: Gordon and Breach Publishers. x, 322 p.

I have not seen the translation but in the Russian
original, the paper is on pages 171-207.

Remark. Unfortunately, the English translation does not contain this paper. The table of contents of the English translation is available here:
[https://www.amazon.com/Alexandrov-Selected-Works-Part-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B07BFS986K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BFS986K)
It only has 322 pages, while the Russian original contains 803 pages.

The Russian original is available for a free download in Genesis library. When searching, be aware that his name has two different spellings in English: Alexandrov and Aleksandrov. The Russian spelling is Александр Данилович Александров.

Comment: That's too helpful! I actually checked the English version of his selected works before asking this question but didn't find this paper. It is a little bit weird that such a standard reference in convex analysis and convex geometry textbooks doesn't have an English version. The authors of these books are not Russian, so I would be very surprised if they all know about Russian.

Comment: @foxell, I suppose that if this result is important, its proof must be reproduced somewhere, for example somewhere in Aleskandrov's many books, or in the papers of people who generalize it. But this is  more difficult to find, and I leave it to specialists in the subject. Unfortuntely the citation indices do not spread that much to the past.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!

Comment: If the question was to find a proof of a.e. second differentibility of convex hypersurfaces, it is e.g. in "On the second differentiability
of convex surfaces" by Gabriele Bianchi, Andrea Colesanti, Carlo Pucci, see http://web.math.unifi.it/users/bianchi/lavori/bianchi_colesanti_pucci_second_diff_convex.pdf.